# Ansible wait_for doesn't seem to work

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm provisioning a new server via Terraform and using Ansible as the provisioner on my local system.

Terraform provisions a system on EC2, and then it runs the Ansible playbook providing the IP of the newly built system as the inventory.

I want to use Ansible to wait for the system to finish booting and prevent further tasks from being attempted up until a connection can be established. Up until this point I have been using a manual pause which is inconvenient and imprecise.

Ansible doesn't seem to do what the documentation says it will (unless I'm wrong, a very possible scenario). Here's my code:

```
- name: waiting for server to be alive
    wait_for:
      state: started
      port: 22
      host: "{{ ansible_ssh_host | default(inventory_hostname) }}"
      delay: 10
      timeout: 300
      connect_timeout: 300
      search_regex: OpenSSH
    delegate_to: localhost
```

What happens in this step is that the connection doesn't wait any more than 10 seconds to make the connection, and it fails. If the server has booted and I try the playbook again, it works fine and performs as expected.

I've also tried `do_until` style loops which never seem to work. All examples given in documentation use shell output, and I don't see any way that it would work for non-shell modules.

I also can't seem to get any debug information if I try to register a result and print it out using the debug module.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `delegate_to` or `local_action` module, `{{ ansible_ssh_host }}` resolves to `localhost`, so your task is always running with the following parameter:

```
host: localhost
```

It waits for 10 seconds, checks the SSH connection to local host and proceeds (because most likely it is open).

---

If you use `gather_facts: false` (which I believe you do) you can add a `set_fact` task before, to store the target host name value in a variable:

```
- set_fact:
    host_to_wait_for: "{{ ansible_ssh_host | default(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

and change the line to:

```
host: "{{ host_to_wait_for }}"
```

You can proof-test the variables with the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        host_to_wait_for: "{{ ansible_ssh_host | default(inventory_hostname) }}"
    - debug: msg="ansible_ssh_host={{ ansible_ssh_host }}, inventory_hostname={{ inventory_hostname }}, host_to_wait_for={{ host_to_wait_for }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

---

Alternatively you can try to find a way to provide the IP address of the EC2 instance to Ansible as a variable and use it as a value for `host:` parameter. For example, you run Ansible from CLI, then pass `${aws_instance.example.public_ip}` to `--extra-vars` argument.

Comment: Sorry, I rolled back to the original version. Of course what I suggested works, I tested it before and got confused after your comment, because I re-run with `gather_facts`-enabled and it didn't even fire for hosts that were down. (also kindly please clean-up your comments)

Comment: does `set_fact` run on the local machine then?

Comment: Run the playbook I included and see for yourself. Why would Ansible call Python on a remote machine to set a value to a variable?

Comment: No that makes sense, and I tested and it does indeed work

Comment: But thanks for questioning. Having gone through a thought process once, next time I'll have more confidence. (and indeed when solving this from the bottom up, I did not pay attention to the preface of the question)

Answer (score 0):

As techraf indicates, your inventory lookup is actually grabbing the localhost address because of the delegation, so it's not running against the correct machine.

I think your best solution might be to have terraform pass a variable to the playbook containing the instance's IP address. Example:

terraform passes `-e "new_ec2_host=<IP_ADDR>"`

Ansible task:

```
- name: waiting for server to be alive
    wait_for:
      state: started
      port: 22
      host: "{{ new_ec2_host }}"
      delay: 10
      timeout: 300
      connect_timeout: 300
      search_regex: OpenSSH
    delegate_to: localhost
```